# Space of Bandlimited Functions

Tags: fourier-transform

I was asking myself about some necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a function to be bandlimited (i.e. its Fourier transform is zero t residing out of $[-B,B]$ for some $B>0$).
Of course, if a function is bounded (timelimited), it cannot be bandlimited.
But for a non-bounded function, how can we tell if it's bandlimited or not?
Or, how can we know if a function is both time- and band- unlimited? Any sufficient/necessary conditions.
I'll be glad if you can share with me some known results.

Thanks!

Comment: $x\mapsto 0 \:$ certainly seems like a bounded (timelimited) function that is also bandlimited. $\hspace{.8 in}$

Comment: a nonzero function cannot be both timelimited and bandlimited, this is a very known result aka Heisenberg's uncertainty 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a necessary and sufficient condition for a function $f$ of the real variable
to be "band-limited". It is called the Wiener-Paley theorem. $f$ must be a restriction on the real
line of an entire function of exponential type. Of course, here one implicitly assumes that
$f$ belongs to an appropriate space which permits to interpret it as a "signal".
For example, $L^2$ (finite energy), or $L^\infty$ (bounded amplitude), or Schwarz temperate
distribution etc.

P.S. This is a mathematical website, and the engineering terminology of the problem may
sound strange to some mathematicians. So let me try to translate:
We are taking about a function of a real variable for which Fourier transform is defined
in some sense. Band limited means that Fourier transform has bounded support, and 
"time-limited" means that the function itself has bounded support.
Of course the function cannot be simultaneously time- and band- limited, unless it is zero.
This is a (very crude) form of the "indeterminacy principle", and also follows
from the Wiener-Paley theorem.

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know how I forgot about Wiener-Paley. I also didn't know it's engineering terminology, almost all I have is books and internet.
Do you recall any other interesting distinguishing property?
Essentially, what I'd like to do is to take L_2 and to divide it into 3 subsets: functions with compact support (CS), functions with fourier transform (FT) with CS, functions that neither they nor their FT has CS.
I guess requiring those subsets to be Hilbert spaces is too much to ask, not to mention RKHS.

Comment: No, those are not Hilbert spaces, because the $L^2$ limit of functions with bounded support can have unbounded support.
And your third set is not even a vector space.